# Execute shell script present in host machine path in vagrant

Tags: bash, shell, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision, inline-scripting

My Vagrantfile is

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
cd /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/
sudo sh startServer.sh server1
SCRIPT
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bolbase"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6000, host: 6000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9060, host: 9060
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 4096
        v.cpus = 2
    end
 end
```

Error Message :

> ==> default: sh: line 1: startServer.sh: not found The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means
>   the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log
>   above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong

In script tag, i mentioned the path as /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/. This path present inside my solaris box. During vagrant up i need execute the below command inside the solaris box

```
startServer.sh server1
```

What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you change this;

```
cd /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/
```

or

```
sudo sh /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/startServer.sh server1
```